# Email To Case Auto Response if the case created status is closed

Tags: salesforce1-app

I have created one EmailToCase with auto Response to the sender that their case has been created. now what i want is when the sender reply back to that mail and the status of that email is closed then again a auto response mail will be send that their case is closed.

I have already created workflow but it sends mail whenever i am changing the status of created case to closed, but i want only if user reply to the created case and at that time if status of his case is closed He will get notification mail.

Answer (score 0):

If user has replied to your email, then only you need to send email. So,

Create a flag on Case object 'Is Email Received for this Case?'. Make this flag to true, when you received an email regarding this case.

In workflow, add condition to send mail. i.e if flag is true then only send the email.